# Navigation Bar Overflow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to dynamically create a navigation bar from a Database to accomodate addition of categories to a website in the future. Therefore the horizontal space of the navigation bar could not suffice in the future.

Goal is to have a scrollable navigation bar, scrollable with the two buttons on the sides. What I would like to do is to have one line of navigation items, so a kind of horizontal overflow. I tried doing it this way, but does not seem to function.

I used flexbox for the full line.. Does this limit me in any way in obtaining overflow on the navigation bar?

What can I do to obtain a horizontally scrollable navigation bar that can be used with side buttons?

```css
li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#flexbox_nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}

#lscroll_but {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#head_nav {
  flex-grow: 15;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#rscroll_but {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="containing_div">
  <header>
    <div id="flexbox_nav">
      <button id="lscroll_but">LEFT</button>
      <nav id="head_nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a>HOME</a></li>
          <li><a>ONEZERO</a></li>
          <li><a>ELEMENTAL</a></li>
          <li><a>GEN</a></li>
          <li><a>ZORA</a></li>
          <li><a>FORGE</a></li>
          <li><a>HUMAN PARTS</a></li>
          <li><a>STARTUPS</a></li>
          <li><a>SELF</a></li>
          <li><a>TECH</a></li>
          <li><a>HEATED</a></li>
          <li><a>MODUS</a></li>
          <li><a>MORE</a></li>
          <li><a>STARTUPS</a></li>
          <li><a>SELF</a></li>
          <li><a>TECH</a></li>
          <li><a>HEATED</a></li>
          <li><a>MODUS</a></li>
          <li><a>MORE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <button id="rscroll_but">RIGHT</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#flexbox_nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  /* max-width: 100%; */
}

#lscroll_but {
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
}

#head_nav {
  /* flex-grow: 15; */
  /* flex-flow: row nowrap; */
  /* line-height: 20px; */
  /* display: inline-flex; */
  /* vertical-align: middle; */
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

#rscroll_but {
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  /* overflow: auto; */
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-list li {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  /* float: left; */
  /* display: block; */
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="containing_div">
  <header>
    <div id="flexbox_nav">
      <button id="lscroll_but">LEFT</button>
      <nav id="head_nav">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li><a>HOME</a></li>
          <li><a>ONEZERO</a></li>
          <li><a>ELEMENTAL</a></li>
          <li><a>GEN</a></li>
          <li><a>ZORA</a></li>
          <li><a>FORGE</a></li>
          <li><a>HUMAN PARTS</a></li>
          <li><a>STARTUPS</a></li>
          <li><a>SELF</a></li>
          <li><a>TECH</a></li>
          <li><a>HEATED</a></li>
          <li><a>MODUS</a></li>
          <li><a>MORE</a></li>
          <li><a>STARTUPS</a></li>
          <li><a>SELF</a></li>
          <li><a>TECH</a></li>
          <li><a>HEATED</a></li>
          <li><a>MODUS</a></li>
          <li><a>MORE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <button id="rscroll_but">RIGHT</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Live Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rcq36w0h/

CSS:

```
li{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#flexbox_nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
}

#lscroll_but{
}

#head_nav{
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#rscroll_but{
}
body {
    margin:0

}

ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    align-items: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nav Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main_style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="containing_div">

        <header>
            <div id="flexbox_nav">
                <button id="lscroll_but">LEFT</button>
                <nav id="head_nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a>ONEZERO</a></li>
                        <li><a>ELEMENTAL</a></li>
                        <li><a>GEN</a></li>
                        <li><a>ZORA</a></li>
                        <li><a>FORGE</a></li>
                        <li><a>HUMAN PARTS</a></li>
                        <li><a>STARTUPS</a></li>
                        <li><a>SELF</a></li>
                        <li><a>TECH</a></li>
                        <li><a>HEATED</a></li>
                        <li><a>MODUS</a></li>
                        <li><a>MORE</a></li>
                        <li><a>STARTUPS</a></li>
                        <li><a>SELF</a></li>
                        <li><a>TECH</a></li>
                        <li><a>HEATED</a></li>
                        <li><a>MODUS</a></li>
                        <li><a>MORE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <button id="rscroll_but">RIGHT</button>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>


</body></html>
```

Script:

```
$(document).on('click', '#lscroll_but', function(){
  $('#head_nav').scrollLeft($('#head_nav').scrollLeft() - 10);
});
$(document).on('click', '#rscroll_but', function(){
  $('#head_nav').scrollLeft($('#head_nav').scrollLeft() + 10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use a carousel plugin. 
>   **Ex: Owl-Carousel**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoWidth:true,
    nav: true,
    navText: [
        'LEFT',
        'RIGHT'
    ],
    navContainer: '#flexbox_nav',
  })
});
```

```css
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

#flexbox_nav{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.owl-prev, .owl-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  z-index: 100;
 }
  .owl-prev {
      left: 0;
  }
  .owl-next {
      right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="containing_div">
  <header>
    <div id="flexbox_nav">

      <nav id="head_nav">
        <ul class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <li class="item"><a>HOME</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>ONEZERO</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>ELEMENTAL</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>GEN</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>ZORA</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>FORGE</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>HUMAN PARTS</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>STARTUPS</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>SELF</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>TECH</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>HEATED</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>MODUS</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>MORE</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>STARTUPS</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>SELF</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>TECH</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>HEATED</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>MODUS</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a>MORE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.. I prefer to avoid plugins so will go for another solution.. Take care!